# Two equations with same label

Tags: equations, labels

I have to translate a dissertation to a researcher. There is a problem I couldn't solve. Namely, there is an introduction chapter where the author has named an equation as `(A)`. Then in the chapter one there is again an equation named as `(A)`. Those equations are not the same in sense that first one has parameter `z` but another has parameter `e^z`. So how can I name two different equations with the same label? For example

> `e^{ix}+1=0` (A)

and

> `$e^{iy}=-1$` (A)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Virtually they're the same. You might add the chapter number in front of the second equation, for instance.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the `amsmath` package, you can specify the displayed label using the `\tag` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\tag{A}
        e^{ix}+1=0
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\tag{A}
        e^{iy}+1=0
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at a possible scenario.

The text has an unnumbered first chapter, where equations are identified by letters, while the body of the book has equations numbered like (chapter.equation).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% this and 'oneside' is just for making small pictures
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\renewcommand\theequation{\Alph{equation}}

\chapter{Introduction}

Some text
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Euler}
e^{ix}+1=0
\end{equation}
some text

\mainmatter
\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}

\chapter{Title}

Some text followed by an equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:easy}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
and here we use an equivalent formulation of an equation in the introduction
\begin{equation}\tag{\ref{eq:Euler}}
e^{iy}=-1
\end{equation}
Some other text

\end{document}
```

Using `\ref` in the recalled equation allows to make this independent of the actual number used in the introduction.

The author might have not used `\renewcommand\theequation` and have assigned “A” manually with `\tag`; but the result would be the same

```
% in the introduction
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Euler}\tag{A}
e^{ix}+1=0
\end{equation}

% in the body
\begin{equation}\tag{\ref{eq:Euler}}
e^{iy}=-1
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the number of the equations conter you could use:

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

right before the second equation (A).

If you want to use the equation number A just for that equation and keep with normal numbering you could use:

```
\begin{equation}\tag{A}
  e^{iy}=-1
\end{equation}
```