# Different equations with the same tag cause wrong reference

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels

I would like to achieve something quite similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392113/two-equations-with-same-label), except that I would also like to reference said equations. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chapter A}
\begin{equation}\label{star1}\tag{$\star$}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
The main equation of this chapter is the Pythagorean theorem, \eqref{star1}.

\pagebreak

\section*{Chapter B}
\begin{equation}\label{star2}\tag{$\star$}
    i^2 = -1
\end{equation}
The main equation of this chapter is the definition of the imaginary unit, \eqref{star2}.
\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\eqref{star2}` points to the Pythagorean. I also get this warning which I am pretty sure is relevant:
`destination with the same identifier  (name{equation.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored <to be read again>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mhh, the MWE as posted works fine for me: The resulting PDF contains two each linking to a different equation. I also get no warning about destinations with the same label. Delete the `.aux` file and compile again.

Comment: @moewe I did. I actually deleted all the aux files just in case. The problem remains.

Comment: With the exact MWE you posted? Can you please show us the complete `.log` file of the (second) LaTeX run. (If it is too long to fit into the question, you can upload it to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: @moewe No, I don't work with MWE. To be honest, I haven't actually compiled it in my machine. I just extract it from my working tex file. I dug around in the aux files a bit and I think I found the problem. Could you please try again with section* instead of just section? I am actually using section* so both aux file name the equation 0.1 but with section they name them 1.1 and 2.1.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am usually very focused to produced an example as minimal as possible I don't always check it. In this case it kinda helped because with the modification I commented above it reproduces the error so we know exactly the problem. I edited the question accordingly. I also added a pagebreak so to make the error obvious.

Comment: Use `equation*` and the problem will disappear.

Comment: thanks for the edit (I deleted earlier comment)

Comment: @egreg It actually worked.! I am gonna guess that since I labeled it manually I don't need latex do to its thing but other than that I have no idea as to why. I also have no idea what campa is talking about but if you agree what is the best practice answer the question so I can accept. Thanks.

Comment: @campa that probably should be the answer (and looking in the aux file that does cause unique names (AMS.2 and AMS.4 rather than duplicated equation.0.1  but I still get the internal duplicate id error for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `hyperref` should be loaded last: only a few packages have to be loaded after it and none of those in the MWE.

However, this doesn't solve the issue. The problem is a race condition: with `equation` the associated counter is stepped and then reset at its previous value if `\tag` is scanned before `\end{equation}`, but it's too late and `hyperref` has already provided an anchor.

The tag being the same is not the problem, although I'd be wary of doing it, because it's probably confusing the reader.

Using `equation*` solves the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section*{Chapter A}
\begin{equation*}\label{star1}\tag{$\star$}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation*}
The main equation of this chapter is the Pythagorean theorem, \eqref{star1}.

\pagebreak

\section*{Chapter B}
\begin{equation*}\label{star2}\tag{$\star$}
    i^2 = -1
\end{equation*}
The main equation of this chapter is the definition of the imaginary unit, \eqref{star2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Which packages should be loaded after hyperref? Also, no need to worry about the reader. Sections are small(5-10 pages) and quite independent.

Comment: @cgss OK, you know your audience. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/4427 for the other question.